# find the dir_name who has less than 2 games played in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g

For example we have this 2 tables

table1:

```
Dir_num |  dir_name
10      | john
11      | vlad
```

table2:

```
game    |  dir_num
101     | 10
111     | 10
102     | 11
104     | 10
104     | 10
```

Now I try to find the dir_name who has less than 2 games played.

```
select * from table1 where dir_num  ....
```

Please help me find pl/sql code.

The output should show

```
 Vlad.
```

Comment: Why is this tagged SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this -- use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT t.dir_num, t.dir_name
FROM Table1 t
  LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t.dir_num = t2.dir_num
GROUP BY t.dir_num, t.dir_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.game) < 2
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c2cc/1).

If you want those in both tables (meaning at least 1 game), then change LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
SELECT t.dir_num, t.dir_name
FROM Table1 t
  INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t.dir_num = t2.dir_num
GROUP BY t.dir_num, t.dir_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.game) < 2
```